# How to update store with a Ember.TextBox data changed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a Ember.TextField in Ember.js template:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='name' id='myname'}}
```

It works fine is saved to store and than to database with standard Ember.js.

But when i change the value of this textbox programmatically:

```
document.getElementById('myname').value = 'other';
```

And save, it is not saved. 
When i add only one letter manually after executing code above, value is saved correctly.

So my question is:

How to change value of textbox programmaticaly so that Ember.js data will be updated? Or: how to change data directly in Ember.js data? Or: how to fire manually saving data from field to underlaying Ember.js data?

Comment: please let me know if my answer didn't help you solve your problem, so I can try to improve it further and add more explanations or code samples

Comment: the example helped me 100%, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example on how to change the value of a textfield programmatically: http://jsbin.com/ilewas/2/edit

Now a little bit of explanation, ember will not be aware if you use plain javascript like `document.getElementById('myname').value = 'other';` to change values, everything in ember is based on [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) so you have to use eighter the data binding mechanism or set the value directly in an action call like in the example using the built-in setter methods.

This very [good blog post](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) by Dan Gebhardt explains in depth how ember's object model works.

Hope it helps.